# Accessing javascript object reference from within member method

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Ok, Im wondering if it is possible to transfer the reference of the object to the functions. If you dont understand what im trying to say, this might help:

```
//so i declare the variable `Editor`
var Editor = new (function(e, d){
    this.edit = e;
    this.dyna = d;
    this.old = ""; //and set these variables inside the object

    this.update = function() {
        var ta = $(Editor.edit)[0].value, dy = $(Editor.dyna)[0].contentDocument;
        //what i want is to be able to refer to the variables (ie. "edit") without using "Editor."
        if (Editor.old !== ta) {
            $(dy).text(ta);
            Editor.old = ta;
        }
        window.setTimeout(Editor.update, 150);
    }

    return this;
})("editor","dynamic");
```

So for the update function, I want to be able to do something like:

```
this.update = function() {
    var ta = $(edit)[0].value, dy = $(dyna)[0].contentDocument;
    if (old !== ta) {
        $(dy).text(ta);
        old = ta;
    }
    window.setTimeout(update, 150);
}
```

And it gives me the variables(edit, dyna, old) from the `Editor` object.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside your function refers to the object of the anonymous base function you have created.

Use `this.propertyName` to access its properties.

```
var ta = $(this.edit)[0].value, dy = $(this.dyna)[0].contentDocument;
```

Comment: Thanks. That was not very smart of me, but I was trying to fix a much larger problem and got confused. Back on track...

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you just using the `this` prefix. So `this.edit[0].value`?

Maybe I am missing something as it's late here...